# Same code but different result

Tags: oracle, powershell, oracle11g, powershell-3.0

I have a strange problem, there is two same code:

The first one :

```
$arraysch= @()
$hash = @{}

Add-Type -Path "C:\app\aasif\product\11.2.0\client_2\odp.net\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"

$con = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection("User Id=sys;Password=password;Data Source=Myserver/oracle;DBA privilege=SYSDBA")
$con.Open()
$cmd=$con.CreateCommand()
$cmd.CommandText="select distinct owner from all_tables where table_name = 'Mytable'"
$rdr=$cmd.ExecuteReader()

while ($rdr.Read()) {
  $arraysch += $rdr.GetString(0)
}

$hash["Myserver"] = [array]$arraysch

$con.close()
```

And the second one, who is in function, but it's same :

```
$arraysch= @()
$hash = @{}

Add-Type -Path "C:\app\aasif\product\11.2.0\client_2\odp.net\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"

function GetOracleDb {
param([string]$servername)
$con = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection("User Id=sys;Password=password;Data Source=$servername/oracle;DBA privilege=SYSDBA")
$con.Open()
$cmd=$con.CreateCommand()
$cmd.CommandText="select distinct owner from all_tables where table_name = 'Mytable'"
$rdr=$cmd.ExecuteReader()
while ($rdr.Read()) {
  $arraysch += $rdr.GetString(0)
}
$hash[$servername] = [array]$arraysch
$con.close()
}

GetOracleDb "Myserver"
```

The first code give me this result in my $hash

Myserver {TEST1, TEST2, TEST3, TEST4...}

And the second one give me this

Myserver {TEST1TEST2TEST3TEST4TEST5TEST6}

Why when I put the code in a function, I don't have commas in $hash values?

Comment: Have you tried initialising `$arraysch= @()` and `$hash = @{}` within the function and then returning them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a difference between powershell 2.0 ans 3.0. I use the following code to reproduce your trouble.

```
$arraysch= @()
$hash = @{}
function test {
param([string]$servername)

$arraysch += "A"
$arraysch += "B"

$hash[$servername] = [array]$arraysch
}

test "coucou"
$hash
```

It works in PowerShell 2.0 not in PowerShell 3.0. For some reason in PowerShell 3.0, in the function `$arraysch` is not seen as a collection but as a `string` so `$arraysch += $rdr.GetString(0)` just concatenate the strings. Just writting `$arraysch= @()` Inside the function solve the problem, but I don't understand the difference.

In PowerShell 3.0 it works with :

```
$hash = @{}
function test {
param([string]$servername)

$arraysch= @()
$arraysch += "A"
$arraysch += "B"

$hash[$servername] = [array]$arraysch
}

test "coucou"
$hash
```

or :

```
$arraysch= @()
$hash = @{}
function test {
param([string]$servername)

$global:arraysch += "A"
$global:arraysch += "B"

$hash[$servername] = [array]$arraysch
}

test "coucou"
$hash
```